How do I bring up the on-screen keyboard in desktop mode on SteamOS?
At least once or twice a week, I accidentally bring up the on-screen keyboard as can be seen in the screenshot below:

But I don't know how I am doing it. Can someone please tell me how I can manually trigger this to bring it up on my own?
This link and many other links says the following:

In Desktop Mode, select a text field then press the Steam button + X.

But I didn't even touch the Steam Deck. So I definitely didn't press the Steam button or the X button. I exclusively use my Steam Deck via a keyboard and mouse.

I'm hoping there's a shortcut key for the on-screen keyboard that I'm sometimes pressing by accident or maybe a way in the KDE environment to bring it up?
